# How to get ID of asp.net textbox multiline mode in Datalist control using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, datalist, multiline

I have got two sections with billing and delivery address within a datalist:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dldirectory" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    RepeatColumns="1" EnableViewState="False" DataKeyField="Id" >
    <ItemTemplate>

                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BillingFullAddress") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200" Height="150"></asp:TextBox>

                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCopy" runat="server" Text="Same as Billing Address." />

                         Address:
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeliveryAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveryFullAddress") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200" Height="150"></asp:TextBox>
                         </ItemTemplate>

            <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
        </asp:DataList>

          <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('input:checkbox[id*=chkCopy]').change(function () {
           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {$('input:text[id*=txtDeliveryAddress]').val($('input:text[id*=txtBillingAddress]').val());   }
       });
   });
```

The above script works fine only when the textbox mode is set to single and the text displayed on the delivery address is copied and pasted on txtBillingAddress when the checkbox is checked, but when the textmode is set to multiline , the jquery fails as textarea is rendered in a different way.

Any ideas how to get exactly the same feauture with asp.net text box set to multi line mode.

Thanks

Updated html:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$CustomersDefaultPaging$ctl00$txtBillingAddress" rows="2" cols="20" id="ctl00_MainContent_CustomersDefaultPaging_ctl00_txtBillingAddress" style="height:150px;width:200px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: When writing Javascript, it's pointless to think about the serverside code. Look at the rendered HTML and write your Javascript to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `textbox` control in multiline mode it renders a textarea so accordingly your selector should be different. `input:text` selector will look for input fields of type `text` it will not select the `textarea`. Try this.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('input:checkbox[id*=chkCopy]').change(function () {
           if ($(this).is(':checked'))  {
               $('textarea[id*=txtDeliveryAddress]')
               .val($('textarea[id*=txtBillingAddress]').val());   
           }
       });
   });
```

Since it is a `DataList` I am sure you have multiple elements on the page So in the above code you should pass the context while selecting textarea's using checkbox element as reference. Try this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('input:checkbox[id*=chkCopy]').change(function () {
           if ($(this).is(':checked'))  {
               //Assuming every item is rendered as a separate table
               //If it is inside a div the change it to div
               var $parent - $(this).closest('table');
               $parent.find('textarea[id*=txtDeliveryAddress]')
               .val($parent.find('textarea[id*=txtBillingAddress]').val());   
           }
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4 then I'd suggest that you look into the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property of those controls.  You can actually force them to use an ID that is a whole lot more javascript friendly.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: i cant set clientidmode to static as i m using datalist

Comment: @MrA: In that case, I'd probably have a particular CSS class that identifies the components in question and let jQuery find the controls by the class names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the textbox using its ID,

```
$('#<%= txtDeliveryAddress.ClientID %>')
```

If you use ID to select it instead, you then don't need to worry about how it renders the tag at client side.